# PHP Curl File Upload sends Empty Upload

Tags: php, curl, upload

I'm trying to convert the following CURL:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
  --data-binary '@myPicture.jpg' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/files/pic.jpg
```

To PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('myPicture.jpg' => "@myPicture.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: image/jpeg";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/myPicture.jpg');

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But my response is `false`. Here is what I get from `print_r(curl_getinfo($ch), true)`:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.parse.com/1/files/myPicture.jpg
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 20
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.28
    [namelookup_time] => 0.187
    [connect_time] => 0.218
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.28
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

Any ideas as to why this isnt working? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the image in the same folder as the php file ? because you specify @myPicture.jpg. Also try with absolute path of the file.

Comment: For a content-type of jpg, you should actually be having, IMO, `$data=file_get_contents("myPicture.jpg");`

Comment: WOOHOO THAT WORKED!!! Want to add your answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ssl_verify_result` has the value of `20`, which means, according to the documentation:

> **unable to get local issuer certificate**
>
> the issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found. This normally means the list of trusted certificates is not complete.

You can try without verifying the peer first:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

If that works, you will have to specify the path of a recent CA bundle. See also: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

---

You should also check whether the file you're trying to upload is in the expected folder. If you specify `CURLOPT_VERBOSE = 1` it should warn you about this as well.

---

**Update**

After checking the API documentation, the service doesn't expect a regular file upload (i.e. `"multipart/form-data"`); rather, a raw upload is required.

This can be accomplished by:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('myPicture.jpg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: image/jpeg"));
```

---

**Update 2**
Passing anything using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` will implicitly set the request method to `POST` and `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When you pass an array, the values may start with `@` to indicate a file upload (doing so should also implicitly change the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`).

The command line `curl` allows the `@` in a few places:

1. using `--data-binary` to specify a file containing raw binary data
2. using `--data` or `--data-ascii` to specify a file containing url-encoded data
3. using `--F` or `--form`

The latter behaves the same as passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and using the `@` prefix. The other two behave the same as passing a string.

Comment: Updated with those options and still didn't work. @Thrustmaster's answer worked =S

Comment: @Garrett I see, the response seemed to suggest an SSL issue; in any case, I've updated my answer after checking the API documentation

Comment: Is that what the @ in the cURL means? Raw data?  I guess I'm trying to understand how the cmd line cURL is Interpreted.  Based on the solution, I'm assuming that means the receiving URL some how expects only a single parameter .. with no key name either?  Seems odd.  I ran into the same issue as Garrett and thought the params needed to be k/v paired in the same @ fashion as the cmd line cURL.

Comment: Had a similar problem (ssl_verify_result = 20) and it could be solved by the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option. Thank you!!